# SFML sprite.setPosition() or sprite.move()?

Tags: c++, sfml

I was wondering what would be the most effective in moving a sprite in sfml? I have found that using both sprite.setPosition(sprite.getPosition() + velocity) works fine for updating position of the object, but also using sprite.move(velocity) would effectively do the same thing.

Does doing this just come down to sprite.move() being shorter to write or would there be specific advantages/disadvantages for using one or the other?

Comment: It doesn't really matter (in my experience), just two ways of doing the same thing - pick whatever is more convenient in your situation.

Comment: I would use `setPosition` when I wanted an exact location and `move` when I didn't care about the position, I just wanted to move by a delta.

Answer (score -1):

Now, regarding moving sprites with `sprite.setPosition()` and `sprite.move()`: you're correct. Both can get the job done. But let me break down some nuances for you:

1. **What Feels More Natural:**

With `sprite.move(velocity)`, it's like you're telling the sprite, "Hey, move this much for me!" It's straightforward.
On the flip side, `sprite.setPosition(sprite.getPosition() + velocity)` is like giving someone long-winded directions when they just asked for the nearest restroom. It works, but feels a tad overcomplicated.

2. **Speed matters:**

Honestly, the speed difference between the two is like choosing between two lightning-fast supercars. For most stuff you're doing, you won't notice a difference.
But if you're the type to chase after that tiny performance boost (I respect the hustle), then `sprite.move(velocity)` might be a hair faster since it skips calling `getPosition()`.

3. **Choosing:**

If you want to plonk your sprite at a specific spot on the screen, `sprite.setPosition()` would be your best pick. It sets an exact location.
But if you're thinking of nudging your sprite a bit here and there (like based on a player's input or some game dynamics), `sprite.move()` feels more intuitive.

4. **Forgiveness with typos:**

If you're prone to making little typos (which happens to the best of us unfortunately), `sprite.move()` is a bit more forgiving. There's less room for slip-ups compared to the longer `setPosition` approach.